# Что я делаю не так при написании widget - теста на Flutter?

Tags: юнит-тесты, flutter

Долгое время не могу понять в чем причина краша теста виджета в приложении на flutter, буду благодарен за любую помощь, и так, по-порядку:

[image: Скрин авторизации по номеру телефона]

1. Предлагается ввести номер телефона, чтобы получить код подтверждения. На начальном этапе кнопка войти неактивная, нужно тапнуть на чекбокс с правилами и ввести номер телефона, тогда кнопка становится активной.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   На скрине часть кода теста, которая отрабатывает корректно, проверяя, что открыт именно этот скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Далее мы заполняем номер телефона и тапаем чекбокс. Тесты со скрина проходят успешно: находим активную кнопку с градиентом и лоадер, тут все гуд!
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Далее должна перейти смена роута и мы должны попасть на скрин ввода кода из смс, но этого не происходит, обращение к АПИ бэкенда мокаю, тут вроде как все норм. Ниже оставлю файл с полным тестом. По итогу падает ошибка.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Что делаю не так не понимаю, если я неправильно подставляю ответ от замоканного сервиса, то тест крашится на этом шаге, а на текущий момент видно, что тест отрабатывает корректно до лоадера на кнопке. Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом, подскажите как решить проблему. Ниже, собственно тот метод, который вызывается по нажатию на кнопку "Войти".
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/models/send_sms_code_for_login_model.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/screens/auth/sms_check_screen.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/screens/auth/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/screens/widgets/linear_gradient_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/services/api/user_api_service.dart';
import 'package:tempojob/utils/colors.dart';

class Routes extends Equatable {
  static const home = '/';
  static const welcome = '/auth/welcome';
  static const smsCheck = '/auth/sms_check';

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [home, welcome, smsCheck];
}

String getRouterKey(String route) {
  return 'key_$route';
}

extension PumpApp on WidgetTester {
  Future<void> pumpRouterApp(Widget widget) {
    const initialLocation = '/';

    final _router = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: initialLocation,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: initialLocation,
          builder: (context, state) => widget,
        ),
        ...Routes()
            .props
            .map(
              (e) => GoRoute(
                path: e! as String,
                builder: (context, state) => Container(
                  key: Key(
                    getRouterKey(e as String),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList()
      ],
    );

    return pumpWidget(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(create: (_) => AuthProvider(const FlutterSecureStorage()))
          ],
          child: MaterialApp.router(
            routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
            routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
          )
        )
    );
  }
}

class MockUserApiService extends Mock implements UserApiService {}

void main() {
  late MockUserApiService mockUserApiService;

  setUp(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    mockUserApiService = MockUserApiService();
  });

  testWidgets('is redirected when button is tapped', (tester) async {
    const phone = '1231231212';
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({
      'phone': phone
    });

    when(() => mockUserApiService.sendSmsCodeForLogin(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {
      return sendSmsCodeForLoginModelFromJson('{"success": true, "message": "Sended"}');
    });

    await tester.pumpRouterApp(
      WelcomeScreen(mockUserApiService),
    );

    expect(find.byType(WelcomeScreen), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.enterText(find.byKey(const Key('PhoneTextFormField')), phone);
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('RulesCheckBox')));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(
        ((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Ink)) as Ink).decoration
                as BoxDecoration)
            .gradient,
        const LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            TempojobColors.orange,
            TempojobColors.paleOrange,
          ],
        ));

    await tester.tap(find.byType(LinearGradientButton));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator)) as CircularProgressIndicator).color),
        Colors.white);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(SmsCheckScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```